# How can I check what ingress controller I have on my kube and what is the default

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have kubeadm and Kubernetes v1.12 without AWS or Google Cloud.

I want to know if the Kubernetes cluster installed already has an ingress controller and if it has two what is the default.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can check for pods implementing ingress controllers (actually with ingress in the name) with:

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep ingress`

And services exposing them with:

`kubectl get service --all-namespaces | grep ingress`

As @[Prafull Ladha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6843187/prafull-ladha) says, you won't have an ingress controller by default. The [documentation states](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#prerequisites) that in "environments other than GCE/Google Kubernetes Engine, you need to deploy a controller as a pod".

Answer (score 1):

There will not be any ingress or ingress-controller defined on the kubernetes cluster defined by kubeadm.

You can define your own ingress resource, read more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

For ingress resource to work you must have ingress-controller running. This controller is unlike other controller, which runs as a part of kube-controller-manager and automatically created as a part of cluster creation.

You need to choose the ingress controller implementation that suits your cluster. Kubernetes currently supports and manages Nginx and google ingress controller. You can also choose other ingress controller like Traefik or kong.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, Istio is a good service mash and it can provide you much more than what a normal ingress has to offer. It can handle all your issue related to services like traffic management, service discovery, load-balancing, metrics and monitoring.

Comment: Good to know that kubernetes doesn't come with ingress controller built-in by default.

Comment: @PrafullLadha Istio will not provide ingress on its own. Ingress Gateway relies on a normal kubernetes LoadBalancer type Service.